# Is there any way to address encoding errors in purchased ebooks

Tags: publishing

I have found a number of ebooks that I have purchased have some glitches in the encoding.  Most often I notice that the pages are mapped incorrectly. For instance, in one case I advance to the next page from 121 and it returns me to 117. In another instance, I advance from 91 and it takes me to page 192. The pages all exist and going in the opposite direction does not seem to have the problem, though I have found a few cases where it did have quirks going backwards as well.

Is there a way to correct this locally without stripping the DRM, finding the incorrect encoding, and fixing it manually? Is there an established channel to go through for reporting these glitches?

Comment: there's something which puzzles me. ePub (or azw3, for what matters) is a liquid format, there should not be such concept as "go to next page"...

Comment: @mau - That concept is part of the ereader... a nook in my case.  If this does not happen in any of the other readers then I will gladly tag this as nook.  My wife and I both had nook colors but different gens.  I have verified that the glitch exists in both versions for several books.

Comment: Have you tried the Nook software on a computer or iPad to see if the glitch exists there? It is possible it's a bug in the reader.

Comment: @Donald.McLean No but I have the original nook color and my wife has the most recent version.  They have different versions of android and the reader.  The problem is the same with both.

Answer (score 4):

There is not a way you can correct an ebook without removing the DRM and adjusting the code.  Depending on where you purchased your ebook you should contact their customer service and they will require that the publisher/author correct the issue and issue you a refund.

Comment: Not sure if such errors are enough for a refund.

Comment: Depending on the seller it is and in the TOS when selling ebooks.

Comment: I had a problem with a book purchased from the Sony ebook store, and this was the resolution. Eventually, as it took them several weeks to figure out what caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As an ebook developer for a large publisher, I recommend contacting the publisher. The best method is probably the customer service contact on the website. When I hear directly from a customer, I try to correct the issue that day.

Answer (score 1):

I build a lot of flowing ePubs and I have had a lot of this kind of error happening when proofreading an open ePub folder, for example with Book Proofer for Mac. The errors most often show up at the end of a chapter, causing me to turn the page several times with old pages showing up before moving on to the next chapter.

Weirdly enough, the epubcheck and code check has returned no errors, and when actually checking the finished book there are no such problems. So I'm thinking it could be device or app specific.